# Localhost has stopped updating when various flask/python scripts are run, how do I fix this?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask, localhost

I've been testing out a few `.py` files with Flask, referring to 127.0.0.1:5000 frequently to see if they're interfacing correctly with the HTML, after running the `.py` I'm getting the following as normal:

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
 * Restarting with reloader
```

However, 127.0.0.1:5000 has suddenly stopped updating when scripts are run, remaining as it was after the first time a script was run since my computer has been turned on (restarting the machine is the only way I've found to take a fresh look at my work). To confirm that it's not an issue within `.py` files or my templates, Flask's [hello world example](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#a-minimal-application) with `app.run(debug=True)` does not update this localhost page when run. Is there any way to remedy this?

**Two things that may or may not be involved with this issue:**
**(1)** I am not using virtualenv but simply running `.py` files from folder directories on my desktop (following proper format for Flask and the template engine, though).
 **(2)** Around the time the problem started I installed SQLAlchemy and its Flash extension, Flask-SQLAlchemy with pip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After tracking the processes down by running `$ netstat -a -o` in the command line, it turns out it wasn't a code error, but rather multiple instances of pythonw.exe, which can be taken care of in the Task Manager. I'm not sure why the processes keep running after I close out of all python windows, or why it keeps communicating with `127.0.0.1:5000`, however, so thoughts on this would still be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thats right. Just press 'Ctrl+Shift+Esc' to open the task manager.
Scroll down to find the 'python3.exe' files and end the task manually.

The reason is 'ctrl+c' doesnt work for me (it just copies the text on terminal window), so I have to manually kill the python interpreter running in the background. Its hard work, but hey atleast you dont have to restart your computer everytime!!