# localhost not reflecting/updating changes to html files

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, windows-10

**The Problem:** Pretty straightforward - I am simply trying to do my work on localhost, but for some reason any time I make a change to an HTML file it does not update the corresponding view. *If* I want the change to be updated I have to restart the web server (using node) every time.

**The tech I'm using:**

- MS Visual Studio 15
- Node
- Windows 10 machine
- Chrome.
- *If you need more info just let me know.*

**What I have tried:** Began with small things and tried working my way out

1. I use nodemon so I run my web server like this: `$nodemon server.js`. So just to test it out, I then ran it just using: `node server.js`. Didn't work.
2. I then thought maybe my HTML file is too nested for Node's file structure to pick up any changes. So I tried editing a file that was only 2 directories down from the root (and I know for a fact it had worked in the past). Didn't work.
3. I then read a post, here: [localhost stopped updating - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24162978/localhost-has-stopped-updating-when-various-flask-python-scripts-are-run-how-do). I thought maybe node/nodemon had a process running from the night before (my computer restarted on it's own) and I just couldn't find the right process to kill. Tried searching for it:

   - Windows Task Manager, didn't show up. Only showed up until I ran the process again via the command line. So, that didn't work.
   - Looked for a process using the command line by typing in: `$netstat -ano | find "LISTENING" | find "8080"`. It returned nothing. So just to be on the save side I typed in: `taskkill /f /im node.exe`. Didn't work.
4. Lastly, as I stated in attempt #3, my computer restarted last night on it's own which is what I believe is causing this issue, I then looked to kill any processes related to MS Visual Studio. My thoughts being I'm getting desperate for an answer. Didn't work.
5. Forgot to mention - Yes, I tried checking for changes on Firefox and MS Edge and no it doesn't update on those browsers either.

This problem is very basic, I think. However, I do not see why it is occurring; I have never ran into something like this. Thoughts/ideas/potential solutions will be greatly appreciated as well! I don't want to have to restart the server every single time to check on my changes.

*Also not sure what tags to even put, so feel free!*

**EDIT:** I tested the same issue with another project and it worked fine. As in, I ran `$nodemon server.js` and made changes to the home page of a separate project and the HTML was updated without having to restart the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it turns out I found the solution thanks to [this stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967259/reflect-html-changes-in-browser-without-restarting-the-express-app). In my server.js file I have set template caching. So I commented out the line `app.enable('view cache');`